# What can prompt a voice announcing "Your phone call is now being recorded" during a phone call?

Tags: mobile, phone, iphone, smartphone, surveillance

A user has reported that during a phone call to the user's SO (significant other), they both heard one or two beeps followed by a voice (English) announcing something similar to "This phone call is now being recorded". The call continued afterwards.

Both were using iPhone 7's on a Danish carrier/network and *do not* use Google Voice (pressing '4' can prompt recording of the call there with a similar announcement being made). Neither the carrier or the network provides such a service as far as we know. The iPhone 7 doesn't have a native call recorder and they have not installed one themselves.

I'm looking for (serious, realistic) suggestions on what might have happened here. What can cause such an announcement to be made?

---

The user was a bit confused and scared, so I may update minor details later, when the user have had time to talk with their SO to detail the event further.

Comment: Are you sure 100% they do not use Google Voice? This can be triggered without pressing 4. Those exact words are the words used. Apart from that the only alternative I can think of that could be a possibility, is one of the phones has been hacked and the malware is using Google Voice to intercept the call?? Just an idea

Comment: Try to dig up more details about what exactly happened and what setup they use on their phones. With the information given a) I could only think of really weird scenarios and b) would have to speculate a lot.

Comment: @ISMSDEV: We are 100 % sure they do not use Google Voice. It is not supported here. All my searches did however point to that, which was why I posted here :)

I will add more information not earlier than tomorrow.